How to use ngx-mask for validating mutliple emails with comma
I am working on adding multiple emailID validation for single input.
Using ngx-mask 7.4.3.
 <input matInput formControlName="documentsRecipients" [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" mask="A*@A*.S*">

How can add comma sepated emailIDs validation for the same.

I am using ngx-mask with email ID validation like this below:
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="m-f-400w">
  <mat-label>Recipients (comma separated)</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="recipients" [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" mask="A*@A*.S*">
  <mat-error>{{reqMsg}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

I need to add comma(,) between email ID.
if any help and suggestion will be helpful.
